# What was Mundungus doing between the Wizarding Wars?

Tags: harry-potter

[The wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mundungus_Fletcher) mentions that he was a member of the original Order, and has nothing between 1981 and 1992.  Do we know what he was doing at this time?  Do we *want* to know?

Comment: Read *Half-Blood Prince* to find out what Mundungus is up to during the second war. And since you asked ... I personally am interested in what Dung was up to during the years you mention, but I'd rather read the books than the HP Wikia. If it were a high quality site, the information about Dung would be cited.

Comment: @Slytherincess just one more example

Comment: I was about to answer based off of the title, but then I noticed that you restricted it to 1981-1992.

Comment: He was up to no good.

Answer (score 3):

As I can't find a canon answer, and I doubt anyone else can, either,  (he's not a very important character) I'll have to say **stealing**. We know he's a crook - it's stated so many times in the books. Why assume he was doing anything different? Most likely he was stealing, conning people out of their money, and avoiding arrest.